# How to set validation on datetimepicker value using C#

Tags: c#

I have two `datetimepicker` control , `datetimepicker1` and `datetimepicker2`.
i have select the date `24-02-2018` in `datetimepicker1`, so please tell me how can i set max value for `datetimepicker2` which shouldn't be maximum then `datetimepicker1` value.

`Datetimepicker2` date should always be *less* than `datetimepicker1` value.

What I have tried:

```
dateTimePicker2.MaxDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

Comment: If it should be less than then try `MaxDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-1);`.

Comment: you need to use custom validator in asp.net

Comment: *Where* have you tried to use the code you've shown? In some form of initialization code, or an event handler? Also some clue about what UI system you're working in would be nice - Winforms, WPF, asp.net, etc

Comment: i have use the code here.  dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged

Comment: Have you tried by binding?

Comment: what if datetimepicker2 max date should be equal or less than datetimepicker1 selected date. ??

Comment: i haven't tried bindind method

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `MaxDate` every time the `Value` in `dateTimePicker1` changes.

You have to listen to the `ValueChanged`-event

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // Some code
    this.dateTimePicker1.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged);
    // some code
}


private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dateTimePicker2.Value > this.dateTimePicker1.Value)
    {
        this.dateTimePicker2.MaxDate = this.dateTimePicker1.Value;
    }
}
```

You should let Visual Studio do the work for you: Select `dateTimePicket1` in your form. Select events (the little lightning in the properties-box) search for `ValueChanged`-event. Doubleclick on the name to add a method which is run on the event. Add you max-date-code there.

Explaination: If you set `this.dateTimePicket2.Maxdate = this.dateTimePicker1.Value` it'll be a copy of your Value. If the `Value` of `dateTimePicker1` changes later on, the `MaxDate` will be still the same. You have to set it again.